# heroku free tier and SSL certificate workarounds?

Tags: ssl, heroku, amazon-route53

DNS beginner here so bear with me-- I have a small heroku node app and I can't afford the $7/m hobby plan that you need to auto generate an SSL certificate. I have a custom domain from AWS Route 53 that points to the app, but only the `www.` address works, not the `https://` address, I gather because I don't have the SSL certificate.

I saw that there were some [cloudfront hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131611/heroku-cloudflare-completely-free-ssl) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185560/heroku-set-ssl-certificates-on-free-plan)) but mixed reviews about whether they work, and they sound a bit too complicated for me, a beginner.

Are there any workarounds? Like, could I have my `https://` AWS address just redirect to the `www.` one? Could I wrap the ssl'd heroku app in an iframe? Or are there other heroku jamstack type alternatives that offer more inexpensive SSL certificates?

Comment: As mentioned by @portatlas, Cloudflare provides free SSL certificate. Yet another instructions how to add Clodflare to Heroku can be found [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react#custom-domain-and-cdn)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use CloudFlare's free SSL with heroku, here is a [blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku) that goes through the process.