# Can't deploy Heroku App (npm err! ELIFECYCLE Exit Status 1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, redis

I have been trying to deploy a blockchain application on Heroku - it's written in JavaScript and includes node.js, redis, and React. While the app is fully functional on a local port, I'm receiving a complex error when I run *heroku logs --tail* in the terminal. Here is the error (I know it's in a code snippet but felt like that would make it more readable):

```js
2021-07-01T03:17:24.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.06 sample#load-avg-5m=0.095 sample#load-avg-15m=0.155 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.061111 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7494260kB sample#memory-cached=4526852kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:20:45.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.18 sample#load-avg-5m=0.15 sample#load-avg-15m=0.165 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.061111 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7494860kB sample#memory-cached=4527028kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:21:21.001119+00:00 app[api]: @ref:redis-concave-32605 completed provisioning, setting HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN_TLS_URL, HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN_URL. by user heroku-redis@addons.heroku.com
2021-07-01T03:21:21.001119+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user heroku-redis@addons.heroku.com
2021-07-01T03:21:21.273031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-07-01T03:21:29.684446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-07-01T03:21:31.855988+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:31.856000+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptochain@1.0.0 start /app
2021-07-01T03:21:31.856001+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build-client & node index.js
2021-07-01T03:21:31.856001+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:32.268523+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:32.268547+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptochain@1.0.0 build-client /app
2021-07-01T03:21:32.268549+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist
2021-07-01T03:21:32.268549+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:32.539039+00:00 app[web.1]: listening at localhost: 39994
2021-07-01T03:21:32.565995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573200+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:352
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573202+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573203+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573203+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573204+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573205+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1514:34)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573205+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573205+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573206+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:708:12)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573206+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573207+00:00 app[web.1]: at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:342:14)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573208+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:223:14)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573208+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573209+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573209+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573210+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573210+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
2021-07-01T03:21:32.573210+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-07-01T03:21:32.589313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-07-01T03:21:32.589692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-07-01T03:21:32.597238+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cryptochain@1.0.0 start: `npm run build-client & node index.js`
2021-07-01T03:21:32.597381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-07-01T03:21:32.597530+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-07-01T03:21:32.597660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the cryptochain@1.0.0 start script.
2021-07-01T03:21:32.597765+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-07-01T03:21:32.607254+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:32.607445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-07-01T03:21:32.607578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T03_21_32_598Z-debug.log
2021-07-01T03:21:32.687486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-01T03:21:32.965635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-07-01T03:21:33.105392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-07-01T03:21:42.791340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-07-01T03:21:45.092457+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.092477+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptochain@1.0.0 start /app
2021-07-01T03:21:45.092477+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build-client & node index.js
2021-07-01T03:21:45.092478+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.463251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.463258+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptochain@1.0.0 build-client /app
2021-07-01T03:21:45.463259+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist
2021-07-01T03:21:45.463259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.896194+00:00 app[web.1]: listening at localhost: 23780
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929244+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:352
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929246+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929247+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929247+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929248+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929248+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1514:34)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929249+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929249+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929250+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:708:12)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929250+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929251+00:00 app[web.1]: at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:342:14)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929252+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:223:14)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929252+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929252+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929253+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929254+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929254+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
2021-07-01T03:21:45.929254+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-07-01T03:21:45.947602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-07-01T03:21:45.948090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-07-01T03:21:45.955537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cryptochain@1.0.0 start: `npm run build-client & node index.js`
2021-07-01T03:21:45.955725+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-07-01T03:21:45.955899+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-07-01T03:21:45.956021+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the cryptochain@1.0.0 start script.
2021-07-01T03:21:45.956142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-07-01T03:21:45.966534+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.966744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-07-01T03:21:45.966868+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T03_21_45_956Z-debug.log
2021-07-01T03:21:45.968683+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:45.968684+00:00 app[web.1]: > cryptochain@1.0.0 clean /app
2021-07-01T03:21:45.968684+00:00 app[web.1]: > rm -rf .cache client/dist
2021-07-01T03:21:45.968684+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-01T03:21:46.031029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-01T03:21:46.260925+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-01T03:23:24.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.255 sample#load-avg-5m=0.27 sample#load-avg-15m=0.335 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6169772kB sample#memory-cached=4894636kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:23:37.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.07 sample#load-avg-5m=0.185 sample#load-avg-15m=0.29 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6173652kB sample#memory-cached=4894796kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:23:58.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.195 sample#load-avg-5m=0.18 sample#load-avg-15m=0.175 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.058333 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7491456kB sample#memory-cached=4527088kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:26:51.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.245 sample#load-avg-5m=0.205 sample#load-avg-15m=0.27 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6172740kB sample#memory-cached=4894916kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:27:07.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.115 sample#load-avg-5m=0.155 sample#load-avg-15m=0.17 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.061111 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7491408kB sample#memory-cached=4527152kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:30:25.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.19 sample#load-avg-5m=0.15 sample#load-avg-15m=0.16 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.0625 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7495212kB sample#memory-cached=4527332kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:33:22.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.165 sample#load-avg-5m=0.175 sample#load-avg-15m=0.245 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6170000kB sample#memory-cached=4895204kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:33:38.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.225 sample#load-avg-5m=0.175 sample#load-avg-15m=0.165 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.061111 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7494848kB sample#memory-cached=4527372kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:36:40.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.17 sample#load-avg-5m=0.165 sample#load-avg-15m=0.225 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6168372kB sample#memory-cached=4895496kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:36:55.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.04 sample#load-avg-5m=0.13 sample#load-avg-15m=0.15 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.066667 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7494652kB sample#memory-cached=4527420kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:39:54.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.115 sample#load-avg-5m=0.145 sample#load-avg-15m=0.2 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6170228kB sample#memory-cached=4895536kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:40:12.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-opaque-73806 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.07 sample#load-avg-5m=0.11 sample#load-avg-15m=0.135 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.058333 sample#memory-total=15628992kB sample#memory-free=7494864kB sample#memory-cached=4527596kB sample#memory-redis=333720bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-07-01T03:43:09.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_GREEN addon=redis-concave-32605 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.14 sample#load-avg-5m=0.125 sample#load-avg-15m=0.18 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=6166928kB sample#memory-cached=4895824kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

And here are the files which the error seems to pertain to:

```js
//pubsub.js

const redis = require('redis');

const CHANNELS = {
  TEST: 'TEST',
  BLOCKCHAIN: 'BLOCKCHAIN',
  TRANSACTION: 'TRANSACTION'
};

class PubSub {
  constructor({ blockchain, transactionPool, redisUrl }) {
    this.blockchain = blockchain;
    this.transactionPool = transactionPool;

    this.publisher = redis.createClient(redisUrl);
    this.subscriber = redis.createClient(redisUrl);

    this.subscribeToChannels();

    this.subscriber.on(
      'message',
      (channel, message) => this.handleMessage(channel, message)
    );
  }

  handleMessage(channel, message) {
    console.log(`Message received. Channel: ${channel}. Message: ${message}.`);

    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

    switch(channel) {
      case CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN:
        this.blockchain.replaceChain(parsedMessage, true, () => {
          this.transactionPool.clearBlockchainTransactions({
            chain: parsedMessage
          });
        });
        break;
      case CHANNELS.TRANSACTION:
        this.transactionPool.setTransaction(parsedMessage);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  subscribeToChannels() {
    Object.values(CHANNELS).forEach(channel => {
      this.subscriber.subscribe(channel);
    });
  }

  publish({ channel, message }) {
    this.subscriber.unsubscribe(channel, () => {
      this.publisher.publish(channel, message, () => {
        this.subscriber.subscribe(channel);
      });
    });
  }

  broadcastChain() {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN,
      message: JSON.stringify(this.blockchain.chain)
    });
  }

  broadcastTransaction(transaction) {
    this.publish({
      channel: CHANNELS.TRANSACTION,
      message: JSON.stringify(transaction)
    });
  }
}

module.exports = PubSub;
```

```js
//index.js

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain');
const PubSub = require('./app/pubsub');
const TransactionPool = require('./wallet/transaction-pool');
const Wallet = require('./wallet');
const TransactionMiner = require('./app/transaction-miner');

const isDevelopment = process.env.ENV === 'development';

const REDIS_URL = isDevelopment ?
  'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' :
  'rediss://:p417528cc1746793a653dccc6de7f0a0e7ed4054f0a5eb651bdcaa74625590bed@ec2-44-193-232-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9790';
const DEFAULT_PORT = 3000;
const ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS = `http://localhost:${DEFAULT_PORT}`;

const app = express();
const blockchain = new Blockchain();
const transactionPool = new TransactionPool();
const wallet = new Wallet({blockchain});
const pubsub = new PubSub({blockchain, transactionPool, redisUrl: REDIS_URL});
const transactionMiner = new TransactionMiner({blockchain, transactionPool, wallet, pubsub});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));

app.get('/api/blocks', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain);
});

app.post('/api/mine', (req, res) => {
  const {data} = req.body;

  blockchain.addBlock({data});

  pubsub.broadcastChain();

  res.redirect('/api/blocks');
});

app.post('/api/transact', (req, res) => {
  const {amount, recipient} = req.body;

  let transaction = transactionPool
    .existingTransaction({inputAddress: wallet.publicKey});

  try {
    if (transaction) {
      transaction.update({senderWallet: wallet, recipient, amount});
    } else {
      transaction = wallet.createTransaction({
        recipient,
        amount,
        chain: blockchain.chain
      });
    }
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(400).json({type: 'error', message: error.message});
  }

  transactionPool.setTransaction(transaction);

  pubsub.broadcastTransaction(transaction);

  res.json({type: 'success', transaction});
});

app.get('/api/transaction-pool-map', (req, res) => {
  res.json(transactionPool.transactionMap);
});

app.get('/api/mine-transactions', (req, res) => {
  transactionMiner.mineTransactions();

  res.redirect('/api/blocks');
});

app.get('/api/wallet', (req, res) => {
  const address = wallet.publicKey;

  res.json({
    address,
    balance: Wallet.calculateBalance({chain: blockchain.chain, address, timestamp: blockchain.timestamp})});
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/index.html'));
});

  const syncWithRootState = () => {
    request({url: `${ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS}/api/blocks`}, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const rootChain = JSON.parse(body);
  
        console.log('Replacing chain on a sync with', rootChain);
        blockchain.replaceChain(rootChain);
      }
    });
  
    request({url: `${ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS}/api/transaction-pool-map`}, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const rootTransactionPoolMap = JSON.parse(body);
  
        console.log('Replacing transaction pool map on a sync with', rootTransactionPoolMap);
        transactionPool.setMap(rootTransactionPoolMap);
      }
    });
  };

let PEER_PORT;

if (process.env.GENERATE_PEER_PORT === 'true') {
    PEER_PORT = DEFAULT_PORT + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || PEER_PORT || DEFAULT_PORT;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening at localhost: ${PORT}`)

    if (PORT !== DEFAULT_PORT) {
        syncWithRootState();
    }
});
```

```js
//package.json

{
  "name": "cryptochain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "start": "npm run build-client & NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' node index.js",
    "dev": "npm run dev-client & npm run start-redis && cross-env ENV='development' nodemon index.js",
    "dev-peer": "cross-env GENERATE_PEER_PORT='true' ENV='development' nodemon index.js",
    "start-redis": "redis-server --daemonize yes",
    "build-client": "npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
    "dev-client": "npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
    "clean": "rm -rf .cache client/dist"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.40.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "elliptic": "^6.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "hex-to-binary": "^1.0.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-nightly.734",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I've sifted through other posts relating to this problem but they're all a bit obscure. If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This error says that the app is expecting `redis` to be installed but it isn’t:

> Error: Cannot find module 'redis'

Fix this by installing the package, so that it becomes a dependency in your `package.json`:

```
npm install redis
```

Comment: Installing redis using npm has changed the error, but only a bit -  the h10 flag doesn't seem to appear, but it still cannot find the redis module. I've updated the error snippet in the original comment with what it shows now.

Comment: Still looks like the same issue to me. You’re pushing the updated package.json? I would suggest trying to reproduce the problem locally by removing your globally installed redis.

Comment: I originally installed redis through Homebrew - I can't uninstall it because the rest of my app which depends on Homebrew's redis will fall apart. I made sure to save the npm module as a dependency on the package.json file but no luck so far...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repository?

Comment: https://github.com/parthj894/cryptochain-project-/settings/access

Comment: You'll need to either make it public or add me to the project (my username is `JBallin`).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious in your repository - I do see Redis in the package.json. Can you clarify how you're deploying to heroku? Btw I found this relevant repo: https://github.com/15Dkatz/cryptochain

Comment: I'm deploying by first using heroku: create, then heroku addons: create heroku redis: hobby-dev -a and the app name, then deploying it using heroku open.

Comment: heroku open just [opens the app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-open-path). try [`git push heroku main`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code).

Comment: error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/glacial-fortress-61470.git'

Comment: It appears that I've overcome the original error but now I'm encountering a new error (updated in OP) that relates to the self-signed certificate. I've looked through Google on this one but nothing seems to work; I tried a bunch of things including setting my npm strict-ssl to false. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185560/heroku-set-ssl-certificates-on-free-plan

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the redis package in the dependencies in your package.json file, so this might be the issue

try reinstalling the package with `npm i redis` and deploy again.

Comment: No luck - I installed redis as a dependency yet it still displays the same error. I had originally installed redis through homebrew so that might be why it didn't show up in the package.json file... but even when I made this change Heroku still can't detect the module.

Comment: Installing redis using npm has changed the error, but only a bit - the h10 flag doesn't seem to appear, but it still cannot find the redis module. I've updated the error snippet in the original comment with what it shows now.