# The page at https://lyrics-chords.herokuapp.com/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:8000/auth/user

Tags: django, http, heroku, https

I've just finished creating a Django-React app and have pushed the changes to Heroku. The frontend (JS and CSS) appear on the website no problem, but requests to the backend result in the following error:

```
[blocked] The page at https://lyrics-chords.herokuapp.com/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:8000/auth/user
```

I've consulted the Internet but no one seems to be getting the same error message. Consulting a friend, it seems as if I have to https secure my backend, and futher researching the subject, it seems that there is no free way to upload a SSL/TSL certificate (reference: [heroku: set SSL certificates on Free Plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185560/heroku-set-ssl-certificates-on-free-plan)). Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, really. Turns out, `localhost:8000` refers to the computer of the user. `https://lyrics-chords.herokuapp.com/` is the server for both the backend and frontend, so updating the backend end URL calls sufficed.

Comment: nice reputation lmao